# Added interaction term, standard errors inflated

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, standard-error

I am running a simple regression of an index of cardiovascular health (Heart Rate Variability) on Age and Gender (as a dummy variable), n=430. I first ran: $$HRV \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1Age +\beta_2Gender$$

To obtain the following results (s.e. in brackets):

> $\beta_0 = 7.47 (0.2) $
>
> $\beta_1 = -0.04 (0.004) $
>
> $\beta_2 = -0.23 (0.09) $
>
> Residual Standard Error = $0.776$

I then wanted to check if Gender was had an effect of the age decline of HRV, so ran: $$HRV \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1Age +\beta_2Gender +\beta_3(Gender*Age) $$

But I wasn't too sure about the results:

> $\beta_0 = 7.53 (0.36) $
>
> $\beta_1 = -0.04 (0.008) $
>
> $\beta_2 = -0.296 (0.43) $
>
> $\beta_3 = 0.0016 (0.0097) $
>
> Residual Standard Error = $0.777$

Could you please explain why my standard errors have inflated so drastically in the second model, in particular on the Gender coefficient? Many thanks in advance.

Edit: I have added a plot illustrating the residuals of the first model (Res1) against the residuals of a regression of Gender*Age on Age and Gender (Res2), as per @whuber 's suggestion:[image]

Comment: I'd be worried more about residual errors. Adding more variables is not supposed to increase the error.

Comment: For insight, create two sets of residuals: (1) the residuals from the first regression and (2) the residuals for the multiple regression of Gender*Age against Age and Gender. If the interaction is going to be useful, there should be a good correlation between those two sets of residuals, so draw their scatterplot to see how they are related.

Comment: Was the residual standard error estimate with a degree of freedom correction?

Comment: it was, yes (thankfully, or else that would be a worrying difference!)

Answer (score 2):

This is a good illustration of the problems of collinearity in your data.  Your values of gender and of gender*age are going to be strongly correlated (especially if you have a limited range of ages for whichever gender you have coded as one in the gender dummy).  All the values of the interaction term are 0 for one gender value - and equal to the value of age for the other gender value.  That means that, for your stats package, those two variables look very similar, and it becomes mathematically difficult to allocate the impact on your dependent variable to one or the other variable.   That "difficulty" becomes manifested in your results by having a large standard error for the estimated slope coefficeints.
Any basic textbook on regression will talk about multicollinearity and its impact on regression results in much more mathematical detail.  In your case, I would probably simply say that adding an interaction term doesn't seem to help much, and would revert to the estimates that do not include the interaction.

Comment: Multi collinearity in the way you described it should have manifested in the original regression.

Comment: The original regression only included the age and gender values -  not the interaction.  My answer is only pointing to the collinearity between gender and the interaction term.  That is not in the original regression

Comment: Unless there was an issue with multi collinearity between Age and Gender, there should not be an issue with the interaction. That's why I think that the issue should have manifested itself in the original regression

Comment: Consider the following case.  6 observations.  3 men, ages 25, 30, and 35.  3 women ages 25, 30, and 35.  There clearly is no collinearity between age and gender.  However, the correlation between gender and the interaction from this data set is greater than 0.95.  There can be big issues with interaction terms even if there is no correlation between the separate components of the interaction.

Comment: Hi @DonDresserLatentView that's very helpful; I was mindful of multicollinearity but I had adopted a view similar to Aksakal's and hadn't thought it an issue. Your illustration is very helpful. If it is relevant at all I ran the point biserial correlation between gender and age and it was surprisingly high (.13). Does this suggest some selection bias in my sample (women who participated tended to be younger?) and if so how should I deadl with it in the regression?

Comment: I would not worry about a correlation between age and gender of 0.13 as far as questions of multi-collinearity and inefficiency of estimates.  If you are concerned about response bias in your data - I really am not the person to answer techniques for addressing those problems.

Comment: @DonDresserLatentView, what if the true model is $\beta_a age + \beta_s sex + \beta_{as} age*sex$? You can't simply omit the interaction because it's highly correlated with sex.

Comment: @SueDohNimh, 13% correlation is not high at all.